# How does the zuc algorithm complete the synchronization?

Tags: stream-cipher

I have already read the following documents:

[Specification of the 3GPP Confidentiality and Integrity Algorithms 128-EEA3 & 128-EIA3. Document 1: 128-EEA3 and 128-EIA3 Specification](http://www.gsma.com/aboutus/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/EEA3_EIA3_specification_v1_7.pdf)

[Specification of the 3GPP Confidentiality and Integrity Algorithms 128-EEA3 & 128-EIA3. Document 2: ZUC Specification](http://www.gsma.com/aboutus/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/eea3eia3zucv16.pdf)

[Specification of the 3GPP Confidentiality and Integrity Algorithms 128-EEA3 & 128-EIA3. Document 3: Implementor’s Test Data](http://www.gsma.com/aboutus/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/eea3eia3testdatav11.pdf)

[Specification of the 3GPP Confidentiality and Integrity Algorithms 128-EEA3 & 128-EIA3. Document 4: Design and Evaluation Report](http://www.gsma.com/aboutus/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/EEA3_EIA3_Design_Evaluation_v2_0.pdf)

and I know the **ZUC** algorithm use the **iv** to synchronize for the frame, but I still don't understand how **iv** synchronization is implemented in real applications. Is the method for implementing synchronization similar to that in the WEP algorithm as show below?
[image: WEP encipherment block diagram]
In the WEP algorithm the output of the process is a message containing the **IV** and ciphertext, is the output of the **ZUC** algorithm also a concatenation of IV and ciphertext ( IV || ciphertext )?

Answer (score 1):

frame counter (32 bit)

you find it in  last paragraph of page 14 in [Specification of the 3GPP Confidentiality and Integrity Algorithms 128-EEA3 & 128-EIA3. Document 4: Design and Evaluation Report](https://www.gsma.com/aboutus/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/EEA3_EIA3_Design_Evaluation_v2_0.pdf).